# Updating existing object values using best way

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I want to update my object values with some predefined value like 5.

Here is my object,

```
let data = {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":5}
```

Expected Output;

```
let data = {"a":5,"b":10,"c":15,"d":25}
```

Here is my attempt:

```
Object.keys(data).map(key => data[key] *= 5 )
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: @CertainPerformance please see updated questation

Answer (score 4):

Just loop through all the new object's key and update it to existing object.

```js
var obj = {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":5,"f":9,"g":11,"h":21}

var newObj = {"a":5,"b":10,"d":20,"h":25}

let keys = Object.keys(newObj)

keys.map(x=>{
  obj[x] =  newObj[x]
})

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 2):

Multiply that values with `5`:

```js
let data = {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":5};
Object.keys(data).forEach(key => data[key] *= 5);
console.log(data);
```

Using **Object.Entries()**

```js
let data = {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":5};
Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, val]) => data[key] = val*5);
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

> The `Object.entries()` method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property [key, value] pairs, in the same order as that provided by a `for...in` loop (the difference being that a for-in loop enumerates properties in the prototype chain as well) .

```js
let data = {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":5}
data = Object.entries(data).map(k => ({[k[0]]: k[1] * 5}))

console.log(data)
```